# Extracting info from nodejs xml2js 'result'

Tags: javascript, xml2js

Using the xml2js nodejs module, I've managed to extract from a (large!) xml document, using the following code;

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    parseString = require('xml2js').parseString,
    request = require('request');
    request('https://fb.motorcyclenews.com/mcn-bfs-fb-marketplace.xml', function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          parseString(body, function (err, result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
          });
     }});
```

this 'works', and a small excerpt of the result is below;

> "dealer_id":["--"],"dealer_name":["--
> Motorcycles"],"vehicle_registration_plate":["--"],"fb_page_id":["--"],"dealer_communication_channel":["LEAD_FORM"],"dealer_phone":["+44
> --"],"dealer_privacy_policy_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/privacy-policy/"],"mileage":[{"value":["552"],"unit":["MI"]}],"address":[{"$":{"format":"simple"},"component":[{"*":"Ivy
> Road Garage","$":{"name":"addr1"}},{"*":"Ivy
> Road","$":{"name":"city"}},{"*":"Lancashire","$":{"name":"region"}},{"*":"UK","$":{"name":"country"}},{"*":"--
> 6DJ","$":{"name":"postal_code"}}]}],"vehicle_type":["MOTORCYCLE"],"dealer_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/api/bfs-dealer/redirect/--"]},{"vehicle_id":["56968134"],"make":["HONDA"],"model":["NSS300
> FORZA"],"year":["2018"],"transmission":["OTHER"],"body_style":["OTHER"],"fuel_type":["GASOLINE"],"drivetrain":["RWD"],"description":["HONDA
> FORZA 300CC ULTRA LOW MILES, TOP BOX FITTED,HAND GUARDS, HEATED GRIPS,
> MINT CONDITION, WHY GO ON THE TRAIN OR BUS SAVE TIME AND MONEY, LOW
> COST FINANCE NATIONWIDE DELIVERY
> AVAILABLE."],"image":[{"url":["https://cdn.images.autoexposure.co.uk/AETA86362/AETV24605587_5.jpg?t=--"]}],"url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/bikes-for-sale/honda/nss300-forza/--/"],"title":["HONDA
> NSS300 FORZA (2018)"],"price":["3,750.00
> GBP"],"state_of_vehicle":["USED"],"exterior_color":["BLACK"],"latitude":["51.7241967327"],"longitude":["0.4833483158"],"dealer_id":["--
> City Motorcycles LTD"],"dealer_name":["-- City Motorcycles
> LTD"],"vehicle_registration_plate":["--"],"fb_page_id":["--"],"dealer_communication_channel":["LEAD_FORM"],"dealer_phone":["+44
> --"],"dealer_privacy_policy_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/privacy-policy/"],"mileage":[{"value":["1793"],"unit":["MI"]}],"address":[{"$":{"format":"simple"},"component":[{"*":"198-200
> Baddow
> Road","$":{"name":"addr1"}},{"*":"Unknown","$":{"name":"city"}},{"*":"Essex","$":{"name":"region"}},{"*":"UK","$":{"name":"country"}},{"*":"CM2
> 9QP","$":{"name":"postal_code"}}]}],"vehicle_type":["MOTORCYCLE"],"dealer_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/api/bfs-dealer/redirect/--"]},{"vehicle_id":["56970343"],"make":["HONDA"],"model":["VISION
> 110"],"year":["2011"],"transmission":["OTHER"],"body_style":["OTHER"],"fuel_type":["GASOLINE"],"drivetrain":["RWD"],"description":[""],"url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/bikes-for-sale/honda/vision-110/--

/"],"title":["HONDA

> VISION 110 (2011)"],"price":["1,250.00
> GBP"],"state_of_vehicle":["USED"],"exterior_color":["Red"],"latitude":["52.2398688251"],"longitude":["0.752311123"],"dealer_id":["John
> Banks Honda Motorcycles"],"dealer_name":["John -- Honda
> Motorcycles"],"vehicle_registration_plate":["--"],"fb_page_id":["7714743854"],"dealer_communication_channel":["LEAD_FORM"],"dealer_phone":["+44
> --"],"dealer_privacy_policy_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/privacy-policy/"],"mileage":[{"value":["5051"],"unit":["MI"]}],"address":[{"$":{"format":"simple"},"component":[{"*":"Kempson
> Way","$":{"name":"addr1"}},{"*":"Moreton
> Way","$":{"name":"city"}},{"*":"Suffolk","$":{"name":"region"}},{"*":"UK","$":{"name":"country"}},{"*":"--
> 7AR","$":{"name":"postal_code"}}]}],"vehicle_type":["MOTORCYCLE"],"dealer_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/api/bfs-dealer/redirect/--"]},{"vehicle_id":["--"],"make":["HONDA"],"model":["CRF250"],"year":["2019"],"transmission":["OTHER"],"body_style":["OTHER"],"fuel_type":["GASOLINE"],"drivetrain":["RWD"],"description":[""],"url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/bikes-for-sale/honda/crf250/--/"],"title":["HONDA
> CRF250 (2019)"],"price":["4,500.00
> GBP"],"state_of_vehicle":["USED"],"exterior_color":["Red"],"latitude":["52.2398688251"],"longitude":["0.752311123"],"dealer_id":["John
> Banks Honda Motorcycles"],"dealer_name":["John -- Honda
> Motorcycles"],"vehicle_registration_plate":["--"],"fb_page_id":["7714743854"],"dealer_communication_channel":["LEAD_FORM"],"dealer_phone":["+44
> --"],"dealer_privacy_policy_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/privacy-policy/"],"mileage":[{"value":["1000"],"unit":["MI"]}],"address":[{"$":{"format":"simple"},"component":[{"*":"Kempson
> Way","$":{"name":"addr1"}},{"*":"Moreton
> Way","$":{"name":"city"}},{"*":"Suffolk","$":{"name":"region"}},{"*":"UK","$":{"name":"country"}},{"*":"--
> 7AR","$":{"name":"postal_code"}}]}],"vehicle_type":["MOTORCYCLE"],"dealer_url":["https://www.motorcyclenews.com/api/bfs-dealer/redirect/--"]}]}}

but what I would like to do now is extract some info from this.

In particular, I would like to find out how many times, for example, the entry of **"vehicle_id"** occurs in the list.

I can then use this for other parts of my testing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output you posted is an object, try this

```
let finalResult = Object.keys(result).reduce( (allNames, name) => { 
  if (name in allNames && name === "vehicle_id") {
    allNames[name]++
  }
  else if(name === "vehicle_id") {
    allNames[name] = 1
  }
  return allNames
}, {})

console.log(finalResult)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Ravi However, when I add this code to my existing code script, no matter where I add a `console.log(allNames)` nothing is being outputted to the terminal. Am I misunderstanding with the `console.log`? Many thanks

Comment: @DarrenHarley You have to take allNames in a variable. I have edited the answer. Check it again.

Comment: thanks for your help again, but with your revised code I'm still not getting anything displayed when I run the test. Thanks :(

Comment: @DarrenHarley Could you please share the input. I would be happy to check and edit the code.